# Using a cookie header to enable piloting a site via the AEM apache dispatcher

Tags: apache, aem

We are trying to allow our business users to be able to verify a new site's production look and feel as well as to allow a select group of internal users to be able to view new sites that are authored and created in AEM.

One idea, is to set up a Launch Page that the general public would see, and for the pilot group, they would set a cookie in their browser to be able to see the pilot site.

We have looked into VHosts settings, but can't spot anything, and are thinking perhaps a conditional pass through rule based on the cookie in the header as being the easiest approach?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably If your publisher is accessible via public ip you may use it to checkout the site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that approach doesn't work for us for numerous security reasons.